# accessing object class after click in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

First see the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    var textToShow = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        $("." + wholeEditableClasses[i]).mousedown(function (e) {
            if (e.which == 3) {
                $(".whichClass").html(/*what to use here*/);
                $(".themeOptionsMenu").toggle(1000);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I want to add a mousedown event handler to some not preknown classes.
I mean I have a list of classes and I want add this handler to them.
In the handler's function I need to access the caller's class.
How can I do this?

Comment: What is the issue with the code you have?

Comment: i want to have the caller's class name instead of /*what to use here*/ . and i want to know how.